# T-test for paired differences of two time series of spatial averages with variable data counts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, spatial, paired-data

Suppose I have two 30-day time series consisting of spatial averages of some meteorological variable like global wind speed, for two experiments (over the same 30 days). Each day, there might be a different number of observations, with some days potentially having very few. The two experiments will usually have very similar numbers of observations on any given day. I only have access to the data counts and the spatial means for each day for each experiment. If all the counts were equal, I can use a paired difference t-test to see if time mean global mean wind speed difference between the two experiments differs from 0. Since that is not the case, how can I discern whether the two experiments differ?

Comment: I am wondering whether the word (and tag) "spatial" is merely clouding the issue and decreasing the probability that anyone will answer. What do you mean by "spatial average"? Either describe the spatial aspect more, so the answerer can take the spatial distribution into account, or rephrase the question without the spatial aspect.